# Skipping numbers in indesign bullets

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is is possible to skip numbers in a numbered bullet list?

So for example it begins 1-10 and the next 10 are skipped so the next bullet is 21. I can see that you can pick the starting number but I don't know how to pick a custom order.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you use 2 separate levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the "starting number" option on each bullet if you don't want them in numerical order. [image: Left: using the "starting number" to jump to 21. Right: using the "starting number" to jump back to 1]

Make sure only the line you want to change is selected. If you have all the lines selected, they will all display your "starting number"